# How to receive CHUNK's of data from recv() in BSD Sockets in C programming?

Tags: c, sockets, websocket, tcp

I have implemented a websocket client library in C using socket. It was working properly with many websocket servers. But when I try to connect with one of my customer server, the websocket message was comes in many chunks of data. For all other servers, when I use recv() it will receive one whole websocket frame completely but this particular server will send that one websocket frame in 2 TCP packets so I have to again use recv() to get the remaining websocket frame. Then I tried to check this server with some websocket client tools and it was working fine. I need to know the logic, to implement the recv() for this and how to concatenate and figure when the websocket frame was completely received to parse the data? Somebody help me with this please.

```
while(1){
  ws_recv_ret = recv(*ws_sock, ws_recv, 1024, 0);
  ws_parser_execute(&ws_frame_parser1, ws_recv);
}
```

Comment: TCP is a *streaming* protocol, its data flows like a stream without boundaries. There simply isn't any kind of "packet" or "chunk" over a TCP stream, except what's implemented in the protocols on top of TCP. And as you noticed, that might cause some data to need multiple receive calls to receive in full. Or you can get a single receive call to return more than a "packet" or "chunk", so you have to handle partial data at the end as well.

Comment: Thank you for your insight but I need to know something about the code snippet kind of example to understand how these multiple call to recv() know its previous data or new data? That's were I can't able to understand.

Comment: Once you have called `recv`, the data it puts into the buffer you provide is lost to the TCP layers. It only exists in your own buffer. Each time `recv` returns with a positive value (you should ***always*** check the returned value) you get "new" data.

Comment: I have used multiple calling to recv() for HTTP implementation it works fine because after the whole data received the recv() will return 0 to indicate server disconnected but in WEBSOCKET the client will be still in connected. Then how to differentiate it from next upcoming messages?

Comment: If you want package boundaries for TCP communication, you need to implement a protocol on top of TCP. It can either contain a header with includes the size of the data, or the protocol could use some kind of separator sequence that mark the end of the current package. It's up to you to process that data according to the protocol.

Comment: Yeah, I am using Websocket protocol. Even If I have used the header to parse the length first and loop recv() according to it. How do I know the data was a chunk of whole data or it was improperly crashed?

Comment: @suriyameras: There is no "improperly crashed" in the middle of a TCP connection. Either the TCP connection gets closed (recv returns 0) or it `recv` gets the next data from the stream in the correct order.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Of course there is such a thing. `recv()` can return -1 at any time for any of a large number of reasons, all but one of which indicate 'improperly crashed'. Unclear what this has to do with the topic at hand.

Comment: @user207421: True, `recv` can also return -1 on error. But it can not happen, that there are data lost in the middle of a TCP connection, so 0/-1 with `recv` always mean that the TCP connection and thus also the WebSockets connection is no longer valid (of course except for EAGAIN, EINTR - in which case one need to retry `recv`).

Comment: @suriyameras "*I have used multiple calling to recv() for HTTP implementation it works fine because after the whole data received the recv() will return 0 to indicate server disconnected*" - since HTTP 1.1, a disconnect at the end of a response is NOT the default behavior. You MUST parse the message properly to discover its true ending.  There can be (and usually are) multiple HTTP requests/responses exchanged over a single TCP connection.

Comment: @suriyameras "*in WEBSOCKET the client will be still in connected. Then how to differentiate it from next upcoming messages?*" - read [RFC 6455](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455), especially [Section 5: Data Framing](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-5) and [Section 6: Sending and Receiving Data](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-6). Each message consists of 1 or more frames, and each frame has a header describing its payload. You have to process whole frames, however many `recv`s it takes to read each frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used MSG_DONTWAIT flag in recv and run it in a loop and append new data to the buffer. After that the recv throws -1 with errno EAGAIN then I break the loop and parse the websocket data. And thanks @[user253751](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106104/user253751) for the explanation, it helps to clear some doubt which arose in my mind about the implementation. The below is the code snippet I used in my library.

```
ws_recv_totalSize = 0;
ws_recv_ret = 0;
while(1){
  ws_recv_totalSize += ws_recv_ret;
  ws_recv_ret = recv(*ws_sock, ws_recv + ws_recv_totalSize, MAX_BUFFER- ws_recv_totalSize, MSG_DONTWAIT);
      
  if(ws_recv_ret <= 0)
    break;
}
```

Comment: If you want to see why this solution is problematic, set up a client to send one byte to your server and then sleep forever.  Boom, 100% cpu usage on the server for as long as the client stays connected. :(. (And if you are thinking it’s not a real problem because a client would never do that, consider that a slow or glitchy network can cause similar problems to occur)

Comment: @suriyameras This still doesn't mean you received the whole websocket frame. You can have random delays at random times. My answer said: *The "packets" are totally unpredictable and you must not rely on them at all whatsoever.* That also includes the time delay between the packets! The network connection might hiccup right in the middle of the frame, and then recv throws EAGAIN because your computer hasn't received the next packet yet, even though you haven't finished receiving the websocket frame.

Answer (score 4):

TCP recv is allowed to receive *any number* of bytes up to the maximum number you ask for. The "packets" are *totally unpredictable* and you *must not rely on them at all whatsoever*.

How do you tell the size of a websocket frame? You use the websocket protocol, of course. The websocket header tells you how many bytes there are in the websocket frame. You need to keep calling recv until you have all the bytes.

If you recv too many bytes then you need to save the extra ones and use them for the next frame. If you carefully calculate how many bytes to receive at once, then you'll never receive too many, but many programs do try to receive as many bytes as possible, because that is more efficient, and so they need to deal with extra bytes.

And of course, because the "packets" are *totally unpredictable* the "packet" could end in the middle of the header. So you need to keep calling recv until you have the whole header, and then you know how many bytes there are, and then you need to keep calling recv until you have all the bytes.

Slightly more annoyingly, websocket headers can have different sizes. So you need to keep calling recv until you know how big the header is, then you need to keep calling recv until you have the whole header, and then you need to keep calling recv until you have all the bytes.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me to understand it more.